# Show that all functions $X : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in a probability space is a random variable.

Tags: probability, proof-writing

> Show that all functions $X : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in a discrete probability space is a random variable. $\Omega$ is a sample space

Answer:

Because the definition of a random variable is exactly of a function $X$ such that $X : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Besides, given that the function is defined in a probability space, $X$ satisfies the axioms and basic properties of probability.

I think that my answer, while not incorrect, is lacking and not rigorous enough. A Math PhD such as my probability professor might not give me full marks for this answer, so how can I improve it?

Comment: If what you wrote was the definition of random variable that you saw in class (and it makes sense to define it like this if you only learn about discrete probability spaces. The definition using measure theory is required for more complicated probability spaces) then there is nothing to prove.

Comment: My class teaches continuous probability spaces as well. But I thought the same thing, in the sense that there is nothing to prove because the problem already explains $X$ according to the definition of a random variable.

Comment: Still, I guess you didn't learn measure theory?

Comment: While this particular class i'm taking teaches probability with calculus, it doesn't involve measure theory.

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense to define a random variable just as a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "$X$ satisfies the axioms and basic properties of probability". What axioms and properties?